# Replace a character if it only appears at beginning

Tags: python, string, file

I have a file that has hundreds of lines. I need to read through the entire file and replace a variable name if its name begins with $ character, for example:

```
String $number1;
int $variable2;
double google$3;
......
```

In this example the code should replace $number1 with Nnumber1 and $variable2 with Nvariable2 so every time there is a $ at the beginning of a variable name it replaces it with an N . However, it should not change the variable name if the $ character does not occur at the beginning. so google$3 remains the same
This is the code I have

```
# Read in the file
with open('filename', 'r') as file :
  data = file.read()

# Replace  string
data = data.replace('$', 'N')

# Write
with open('filename', 'w') as file:
  file.write(data)
```

However the result I'm getting is not the one I want. I'm replacing every occurrence of $ to N I just want the beginning $ to be replaced.

```
String Nnumber1;
int Nvariable2;
double googleN3;
```

Edit: There is no guarantee what comes before the $ character it could be anything

Comment: Because you already replaced `$` by `N`, what you want is to replace ` $` by `$N`. i.e. `data = data.replace(' $', '$N')`. Notice that space before `$` sign

Comment: Does the string begin with ```$var``` or by ```var $number...```?

Comment: Do you know how to write code that checks whether the string starts with the `$`? If you have that, can you see how to use it to solve the problem?

Comment: Is every occurrence of `$` at the start of a string guaranteed to be a variable? Or are we looking for the pattern `var $...`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The string begins with `var $number` . if $ occurs at the beginning of a variable it needs to be changed like int $x would be changed to Nx.

Comment: This looks like a file containing code. If you tell us the language it is in, maybe people could give more complete answers. For example, since you are changing the variable name, you will need to change the name everywhere it is used. Those occurrences presumably won't be preceded by `var`. If there's guaranteed to be a space before the variable name everywhere, then you could just replace `' $'` by `' N'`, but what if there could be a space before `$` elsewhere? What if there could be variables _without_ spaces, such as if you did `$number1*$number2`?

Comment: @AronChabane And what about that "number"? Are all "number or there are some other string as well?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes, My mistake there is no guarantee what comes before $ it could be anything so whatever is before $ remains the same just the $ changes

Comment: @AronChabane You have to provide a complete example. Which will have every pattern. If your question was clear, then it won't be hard for us to answer also and you also don't have to edit it time to time. So, read your file carefully and edit last time, with all of the pattern available in your file.

Comment: There is no pattern it could literally be anything before $

Comment: @AronChabane What about after `$`??

Comment: There could be anything as well. I will update my example it gave the wrong impression

Comment: My last believe, is white space before $ sure?  @AronChabane yeah you told _There is no guarantee what comes before the $ character it could be anything_ but curious?

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on question change:**

```
import re

pattern = r'(?<![A-Za-z0-9])\$([A-Za-z_])'

filename = 'varnumbers.txt'

# Read in the file
with open(filename, 'r') as file :
    data = file.read()

# Replace  string
data = re.sub(pattern, r'N\1', data)

# Write
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Changes...

```
var $number1;
var $number2;
var number$3;


String $number1;
int $number2;
double number$3;

$number1*$number2
```

To...

```
var Nnumber1;
var Nnumber2;
var number$3;


String Nnumber1;
int Nnumber2;
double number$3;

Nnumber1*Nnumber2
```

**Additional:**

If you have a text editor with `regex` search ability (Atom, VSCode, Sublime, Notepad++, etc.) you could just use the pattern in the editor.  If your task is for more files Python and scripting may be better as you can loop through lots of file.

**Example replacing in Sublime (old regex shown in the screenshot):**

[image]

Comment: Actually `r's+(\$)` should be `r'\s+(\$)`. You forget ```\``` before `s+`

Comment: thanks! updated it again to be more robust :o)

Comment: Thanks! What does  the N\1  do in this line `re.sub(pattern, r'N\1', data)`

Comment: `re.sub()` has three parameters in it.  First the regex pattern to use from the variable `pattern`; second what to replace match with if it finds something and in this case it puts back a literal `N` char plus whatever was captured in the first group of `\1`; and the final parameter is `data` that is the text from the file.

Comment: @AronChabane does it answer the question?  I based the regex on what is allowed for Perl variables so `$` and then A-Z (upper or lowercase) or an underscore.  I hope it helps :o?

Comment: Yes it does and it fixed it. the identifier for my purposes can only start with A-Z (upper or lower case) and then contain alphabetic characters, numeric characters, the underscore, and the dollar sign (a-z A-Z 0-9 _ $ ). So does the above regex fix it completely?

Comment: You can have numbers in the variable name and they will match but they cannot be immediately after the `$` char.

Comment: @MDR I'm using the first pattern you posted because it's the one that works with the file I have `pattern = r'\s+(?:\_)(\w+)'` It works fine when the variable is declared and throughout the program but, if it's in an if statement it doesn't change the name for example: if ($T$17) remains the same does not change to if (NT$17). Thoughts?

Comment: what language is this?  what is `if ($T$17)`

Comment: it's Verilog. Say a variable was declared `wire $T_17` then with the regex it changes it to 'N_17' latter on in the program when the variable is used in an if statement the $ doesn't get changed to N so it's `if ($T_17)`  instead of `if (NT_17)`.

Comment: Have you tried the latest regex?  `\$([A-Za-z_])` and replace with `N\1` as per the above current answer?

Comment: @AronChabane i've added a demo link in the answer to show what it matches.  Compare the top panel (input) with the bottom for what gets replaced (flick back and forth).  Looks OK to me but let me know. :o)

Comment: @MDR. Yes it fixes the if problem. But, it adds an N in the middle of a variable.So, `hello$go$gle` becomes `helloNg0Ngle`

Comment: Try `(?<![A-Za-z0-9])\$([A-Za-z_])`

Comment: Fixes it. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @AronChabane Np.  Glad it helped.  Don't forget to mark the answer and vote on any of the posts that helped your question.

Comment: You know, you never marked this as an answer? :o(.  Anyway, I don't think it's the regex as `variable_name = pp_ct__tt;` contains no `$` symbol so it won't match anything in that string.  Perhaps look at the way you are running it.  Maybe there is something else but looking at it the regex cannot be causing that.  Put that string in a new file along with the examples from the question and test.  If there is a problem you should post what you're doing and the result (probably best as a new question now time has passed).

Comment: Apologies, I did mark it as an answer. Stack overflow didn't let me. I don't have enough reputation. About the Regex I posted the wrong one it was supposed to be  2 successive `$$` when a statement has 2 successive `$$` in a variable name like so, `variable_name = pp$ct$$tt;` it gets converted to `variable_name = pp$ct Ntt;`

Comment: The regex can be updated.  Try: `(?<![A-Za-z0-9$])\$([A-Za-z_])` Just this is not the best way to do it.  I mean: just throwing in extra chars based on one mismatch at a time.  Anyway, try the new regex.

Answer (score 0):

If all hundred lines are same as provided example then this will definitely work. But If there is any difference then I can tell you this will completely work.:

```
# Read in the file
with open('filename', 'r') as file :
    data = file.readlines()

newdata=[]
for line in data:
    if line[4:].startswith("$"):
    # OR
    if a.replace("var ","").strip().startswith("$"):
        newdata.append(line.replace("$","N"))
    else:
        newdata.append(line)

# Write
with open('filename', 'w') as file:
    for n in newdata:
        file.write(n)
```

Or try this, as @Emad Khaleghpanah said:

```
newdata=[]
for line in data:
    newdata.append(line.replace("var $","var N"))
```

Or If "$number1" "number" is sure then :

```
newdata.append(data.replace("$n","Nn"))
```

Your example always have $number1/2/3..... pattern.

Comment: You mean it wont work if the lines are different?

Comment: No, I mean pattern are different.

Comment: What if there's whitespace at the start of the line?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I had clearly mentioned that, right? You don't have to ask me!!!

Comment: You said _"But If there is any difference then I can tell you this will completely work"_. I'm suggesting a possibility where there is a difference and it _won't_ work.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yeah! I could understand but what does _What if_ mean? Actually I had edited and solved that problem as well. :)

Comment: Yes, I understand the lines do vary and whitespace is also different so it wouldn't work

Comment: @PranavHosangadi and if we start taking about what if then there could be 1000 of what if in 100 lines so, I had mentioned it won't work for either wrong pattern. If that will be the issue then OP should provide detailed information and example.

Comment: @AronChabane Have you checked the last edit??